# How do I convert Solana Wallet keypair to KeyObject in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, solana, solana-web3js

```
const keypair = 'wallet_keypair';
const keypairBuffer = new Uint8Array(base58.decode(keypair));
const user1PrivateKey = base58.encode(keypairBuffer.slice(0, 32));
const user1PublicKey = base58.encode(keypairBuffer.slice(32));
```

I'm currently doing this to extract public and private key from the keypair but I get them back as string. I want to use them further with crypto package on Diffie-Hellman algorithm but it expects the their value to be type of `KeyObject`.

```
const sharedSecret = crypto.diffieHellman({
  privateKey: crypto.KeyObject.from(user1PrivateKey),
  publicKey: crypto.KeyObject.from(user2PublicKey),
});
```

I tried a lot but I'm unsuccessful in converting those pub and private string to `KeyObject`. Can someone help me out here?